# Usage of に in this sentence

Tags: particle-に

そんなメアを飛鳥がカメラ**に**何度も収めている。

Asuka *gathered(?) many (photographs) of Mare via his camera*  ??

Aside from the odd use of 収める, why did they use に over で in this sentence?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be similar to how in English we can say we "caught" something in our camera.  The idea being that the film is in the camera and film captures the image.  In this case, に makes sense as the location of where the image is (as opposed to how the image was captured).

There is an on-line thesaurus for which a web search of [写真に収める](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F%E3%81%AB%E5%8F%8E%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B) shows up.
And [this web site](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1166036041) explains as follows:

> 私は写真に収める＝写真を撮る。
>   カメラに収める＝カメラの中に入れる。
>   という印象を持ちます。
>   しかし、カメラに入れるということは
>   写真を撮ることだと容易に想像出来るので、
>   どちらでもよいように思います。

Comment: Isn't the op confusing the "direction" particles に/で with the "indirect object marker particle"　に? if he used で it would rather sound like "by camera" and not "in the camera" I think

Comment: @FelipeOliveira I agree.  But also, I think the OP is thinking "took the picture **with** a camera" in which case the instrument use of で makes some sense.

Comment: yeah, but probably to mean "with the camera" you'd need a different verb at the end, right? The one that is in the sentence doesn't seem to fit

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Exactly, hence my interpretation.  I'm not sure, but are you suggesting that I amend my answer?

Comment: I did one answer my own, I just felt that maybe further explanation was needed, see what you think

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the direction particles **に/で** that express direction:

> 大学に行っている (daigaku ni itteiru) I am going to college.
>
> あの店で働く (ano mise de hataraku) I work at that store.

Now the に particle you have in your sentence is the **indirect object marker**, you seem to already know the **direct object marker を**... For instance:

> あなたは彼女に何をしている？ (anata wa kanojo ni nani wo shiteiru?) what are you doing to her?

You are doing something (何) that's why を marks 何 with the verb している, but that action is done to someone, therefore the indirect object 彼女 which have to be marked with に.

> そんなメアを飛鳥がカメラに何度も収めている。 (Sonna mea wo Asuka ga kamera ni nando mo osameteiru) Asuka have many picture of such mare in the camera.

if you used で it would sound like "by camera", "with the camera" so you'd need a different verb, and of course you'd be using a different particle, not the indirect object marker!

Comment: I see.  Good point.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why に is chosen is because of the verb 収める, which in this case can mean to "store". Going with the sense of storage, it can be thought of in the sense of Asuka storing pictures **into** the camera. This gives the direction that に requires.